# Creating a user specific Gallery area PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, gallery

Some please help me with coding the below piece!

So at the moment I have a place where members can set up a profile that displays all there information. I now want to give the user an option to upload images. and have a personal Gallery area.

All the tutorials i seem to find only show me how to do an image upload. And not specific to users that there gallery area will have other peoples work in it.

I assume this will need a database to make it user specific? or work off the $_SESSION variable? I just dont know how to go about doing this.

im totally lost can someone point me in the right direction?

Below is my current gallery.php code which just pretty much generates thumbnails and displays all given images in the uploads folder.

How would I go about editing this just to display images for the user in a session or given user profile?

```
    <?php
if (isset($_GET['img'])){
    //make thumbnail
    if(file_exists($_GET['img'])){
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(120);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

        $src_size = getimagesize($_GET['img']);

        if ($src_size === false){
            die('That does not look like an image.');
        }

        $thumb_width    = 200;
        $thumb_height   = 150;

        if ($src_size['mime'] === 'image/jpeg'){
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img']);
        }else if ($src_size['mime'] === 'image/png'){
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['img']);
        }else if ($src_size['mime'] === 'image/gif'){
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($_GET['img']);
        }

        $src_aspect = round (($src_size[0] / $src_size[1]), 1);
        $thumb_aspect = round(($thumb_width / $thumb_height), 1);

        if ($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect){
            //higher than thumb
            $new_size = array ($thumb_width, ($thumb_width / $src_size[0]) * $src_size[1]);
            $src_pos = array (0, (($new_size[1] - $thumb_height) * ($src_size[1] / $new_size[1])) / 2);
        }else if ($src_aspect > $thumb_aspect){
            // wider than thumb
            $new_size = array(($thumb_width / $src_size[1] ) * $src_size[0], $thumb_height);
            $src_pos = array((($new_size[0] - $thumb_width) * ($src_size[0] / $new_size[0])) / 2, 0);
        }else{
            // same shape as thumb
            $new_size = array($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
            $src_pos = array(0, 0);
        }

        if ($new_size[0] < 1) $new_size[0] = 1;
        if ($new_size[1] < 1) $new_size[1] = 1;

        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $src_size[0], $src_size[1]);

        if ($src_size['mime'] === 'image/jpeg'){
            imagejpeg($thumb, "thumbs/{$_GET[ 'img' ]}");
        }else if ($src_size['mime'] === 'image/png'){
            imagepng($thumb, "thumbs/{$_GET[ 'img' ]}");
        }else if ($src_size['mime'] === 'image/gif'){
            imagegif($thumb, "thumbs/{$_GET[ 'img' ]}");
        }

        header("Location: thumbs/{$_GET[ 'img' ]}");
    }

    die();
}

if (is_dir('./thumbs') === false){
    mkdir('./thumbs', 0744);
}

$images = glob('*.{jpg, jpeg, png, gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

?>

            <?php

            foreach ($images as $image){
                if (file_exists("./thumbs/{image}")){
                    echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img src=\"thumbs/{$image}\" alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";
                }else{
                    echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img src=\"?img={$image}\" alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";

                }
            }

            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one suggestion for you.
 Create one table for "**Gallery**"
 and insert data about image name and also user_id and this user_id
 will be id of logged user and that you can fetch from session when
 specific user is logged in.  This is the way you can manage your image
 gallery with specific user is logged in. Let me know if you need more
 help.. Cheers

```
<?php
   $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id=".$uid);
 ?>
```

Here, you can use above result set for display images for specific user only.

Comment: Hi Milap, thanks for the quick reply! So i posted my php code above that pretty much just displays all images in the uploads folder. Once i have the database set-up what would I need to change in this code to only display images for a given user? :)